# Format bash-script output

Tags: bash, format, alignment, stdout

I'm searching for a while now if theres a special format-argument for `printf` or `echo`. I always see this kind of output when i start my ubuntu.
My goal is to print a text like this:

```
Setting up locals                  [DONE]
Starting simulation                [DONE]
Receiving Data                     [FAIL]
Retry operation                      [OK]
```

The information in brackets should always be aligned on the right border of the terminal and colored.

Can someone give me a hint, how i can arrange that?

Thank you and BR

Comment: Have you tried looking at what does that printing for your computer's startup scripts?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually i have no idea where i find this script :(

Comment: Somewhere in upstart presumably though I don't know where as I don't know upstart at all. But ultimately it is just control codes to color the output and position the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

The following bash will align the Severity to the right of the terminal.

```
log_msg() {
    MSG="$1"
    SEVERITY="[$2]"
    let COL=$(tput cols)-${#MSG}

    printf "%s%${COL}s" "$MSG" "$SEVERITY"
}
```

Usage:

```
log_msg "Setting up locals" "DONE"
log_msg "Starting simulation" "DONE"
log_msg "Receiving Data" "FAIL"
log_msg "Retry operation" "OK"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
### Config ###
red="\033[91m"
green="\033[92m"
yellow="\033[93m"
blue="\033[94m"
viol="\033[95m"
cyan="\033[96m"
none="\033[0m"

printf "$viol%40s$none" "$testMessage..."
# execute test here 
/path/test > output 2>&1
ret=$?
if [ $ret -eq 0 ]; then
    printf "$green%10s$none\n" "[PASS]"
else
    printf "$red%10s$none\n" "[FAILED]"
fi
```